# Principle of least privilege on Office 365 OneDrive for Business

Tags: office-365, security, access, onedrive-for-business

Does anyone know how to implement the principle of least privilege on OneDrive for Business on an Office 365 tenant?

I would like to have a way for an automated process to be able to only *upload* to a certain path on OneDrive/Sharepoint but not able to *list or download* the files.

Does anyone know of a solution? Ideally without having to create separate users on Office 365 and paying for their licenses, as that would become expensive very quickly considering I would need over a dozen accounts.

Comment: While you can grant Read privileges without granting editing or uploading permissions, I do not believe the opposite is true.  SharePoint generally requires Read access as a prerequisite to be able to grant access to create new items and files.

Answer (score 0):

If you can upload, you have to be able to read, but before you go too far down this path why are you trying to share and lock down a onedrive, SharePoint should typically be used for this kind of activity.